# MVC ExtractAssociatedIcon show icon in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to display a file icon in one of my views.

@System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"C:/Users/User1/Desktop/test.txt")

Shouldn't this display the icon? Do I need a img tag or something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just have the file contents on the browser. You will need to use an `<img>` tag and have the server return the file stream:

Quick disclaimer: I do not have VS with me, so this is just pseudo-code:

```
public FileResult Icon()
{
    var stream = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"C:/Users/User1/Desktop/test.txt")

    return new FileStreamResult(stream, "image/png");
}
```

Then, just reference the action method:

`<img src="/MyController/Icon">`

Comment: Hey thanks but how do i convert System.Drawing.Icon to System.IO.stream?